# UIDocumentPickerViewController is showing flipped content in arabic

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

this is how I open the document picker

```
func openDocuments(){
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"],in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true) {
        }

    }
```

notice how the cells have flipped labels

[image]

PS:

I have

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

because the app I'm developing is in arabic only

Comment: As far as I know, applying forced semantics with `UIView.appearance()` will apply it to all views, so you need to apply it to individual views where necessary. I have no experience of developing or localisation for languages with right-to-left semantics, but shouldn’t the user’s device manage this automatically if they are using Arabic as the device language?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **browser** layout in `UIDocumentPickerViewController` follows device's layout direction according to the language before presenting `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

```
    if Locale.current.languageCode == "ar" {
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    } else {
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple

```
documentPicker.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

fixed this, but I still find it weird though.

Answer (score 0):

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.